# Making Optional Input Payload in Golang

Tags: go, sdk, payload

I've been building SDK for a EL Platform. While creating an event there are multiple payloads to input. But there are three payloads which are mandatory and others are optional . so The problem is that I don't know how to make it optional.

```
func (e *Events) Create(title, eventType, subType string, skills []string, prerequisite, description, about, subTitle string, preference map[string]bool) (string, error) {
    url := "https://api-dev.einstonlabs.com/api/v1/events"
    headers := map[string]string{
        "Content-Type":  "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + e.instance.Token,
    }

    payload := map[string]interface{}{
        "title":   title,
        "type":    eventType,
        "subType": subType,
    }

    if skills != nil {
        payload["skills"] = skills
    }
    if prerequisite != "" {
        payload["prerequisite"] = prerequisite
    }
    if description != "" {
        payload["description"] = description
    }
    if about != "" {
        payload["about"] = about
    }
    if subTitle != "" {
        payload["subTitle"] = subTitle
    }
    if preference != nil {
        payload["preference"] = preference
    }

    jsonPayload, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error encoding JSON payload: %v", err)
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(url, headers["Content-Type"], bytes.NewReader(jsonPayload))
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error creating event: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var response map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&response); err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error parsing response JSON: %v", err)
    }

    if status, ok := response["status"].(bool); ok && status {
        data := response["data"].(map[string]interface{})
        return data["id"].(string), nil
    }

    message, _ := response["message"].(string)
    return "", fmt.Errorf("event creation failed: %s", message)
}
```

I'm Sharing the code below. only title, eventType and subType are mandatory and others in the parmeters are optional

Answer (score 1):

My habit, when there are more than 3 parameters, it is better to create a structure to carry the parameters.

```
type CreateArgs struct {
    Title, EventType, SubType                  string
    Skills                                     []string
    Prerequisite, Description, About, SubTitle string
    Preference                                 map[string]bool
}

func (e *Events) Create(args CreateArgs) (string, error) {

}
```

For your current code, Maybe it's easier this way

```
type Payload map[string]any

func (e *Events) Create(p Payload) (string, error) {
    // todo check the required filed
    if _,ok := p["title"];!ok{
        return "",fmt.Errorf("title is required")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `payload` being a map it's better to introduce a response struct with `json:..` tags so that it could be marshaled to a json string utilizing the full strength of `encoding/json` library. Optional fields should be marked with `omitempty` tag, so the marshaller would not include them in the output.

[Docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json):

> The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string.
> As a special case, if the field tag is "-", the field is always omitted. Note that a field with name "-" can still be generated using the tag "-,".

So, the struct would be like this

```golang
type Payload struct {
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    EventType string `json:"type"`
    SubType   string `json:"subType"`

    // next fields will be skipped if their value is empty
    // (e.g. empty string, 0, false, nil etc.)
    OptionalString string `json:"optional_string,omitempty"`
    OptionalInt    int    `json:"optional_int,omitempty"`
}
```

Make sure all fields are exported (capitalized) so that the lib could read them.

The same consideration applies to `response`. A strictly typed struct instead of a `map[string]interface{}` would eliminate all type assertions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the options pattern here.  In this pattern,

- a function's mandatory parameters appear in its signature as usual,
- its optional parameters are communicated with a variadic list of type `func(o *options)`.  These are used by the receiving function to set an options struct to the desired state.

This article, [Functional Options in Go: Implementing the Options Pattern in Golang by Soham Kamani](https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/options-pattern/), describes the pattern, and [a small example](https://go.dev/play/p/5pupp8L_uRm) is below.  I also found [an example of this pattern in Apache's Gremlin driver](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3d42e0c1387e750bbbf728e33085b94ca00bbe2d/gremlin-go/driver/driverRemoteConnection.go#L70), where it is used to configure database connections.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type (
    options struct {
        message string
    }
    update func(*options)
)

var defaults = options{"Hello, 世界"}

func greet(prefix string, updates ...update) {
    o := defaults
    for _, u := range updates {
        u(&o)
    }

    fmt.Println(prefix, o.message)
}

func main() {
    greet("defaults: ")
    greet("options: ", func(o *options) { o.message = "Hello, World" })

    // Output:
    // defaults:  Hello, 世界
    // options:  Hello, World
}
```